# Search for a specific string in a list of files located in a directory Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file

how would look for a specific string in a list of files in a given directory using batch? For example the following string RTW4OTO150227074405851I2631911150227CAC.

I Have tried this but it is not working:

```
for %%f in (payment.*) do findstr /i /m /p /c:"RTW4OTO150227074405851I2631911150227CAC" "%%f"" >> results.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a FOR loop:

```
findstr /i /m /p /c:"RTW4OTO150227074405851I2631911150227CAC" payment.* >results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If Powerhsell is an option you can try

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Myfolder -Filter RTW4OTO150227074405851I2631911150227CAC -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fnr](http://findandreplace.codeplex.com/) find string you want support regex plus you can recurse search all sub directory search for specific string then change to any thing you want it 
example

```
.\fnr.exe --cl --dir "c:\" --filemask "*.txt" --find "hi" --replace "bye" --includeSubDirectories
```

or

```
dir c:\ /a/b | findstr "RTW4OTO150227074405851I2631911150227CAC" >1.txt
```